# Парсинг ajax-содержимого

Tags: ajax, синтаксический-анализ

Добрый вечер! Есть задача отпарсить страницу с ajax-содержимым. Точнее только это содержимое мне и нужно. Не ограничен ничем. Полагаю, мне нужно нечто вроде эмуляции браузера.

Comment: @Hlogeon, А не просветите меня, что такое страница "с ajax-содержимым".

Comment: если я правильно понял, вам нужно распарсить ответ сервера на запрос вида `http://site.com/ajaxapi/somedata`, если нет, уточните вопрос

Comment: http://exist.ru/cat/Accessory/Cars/Acura/CL_%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B5?g=9&flag=4

Вот к примеру страничка, ее часть, что содержится в table.tbl - подгружается с помощью javascript, именно эта часть мне и нужна.